Smart Slider 3 Background Video auto play issue
I am trying to disable the autoplay feature for short MP4 background videos hosted on my server through the Smart Slider 3 plugin, so that they only play on mouse-over. Unfortunately, despite trying numerous JavaScript variations across hundreds of divs, I haven’t succeeded. All videos are muted, by the way. I even attempted to prevent autoplay for all MP4 videos on the site, but again without success. I would appreciate your support, and I wish you a great day. The last codes I tried is below...
Url: https://sedaulgen.com/yeni-anasayfa
An example of some problematic code:
<video class="n2-ss-slide-background-video intrinsic-ignore data-tf-not-load" style="opacity:1;" data-mode="fill" playsinline="playsinline" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" onloadstart="this.n2LoadStarted=1;" data-keepplaying="1" preload="none" muted="muted" loop="loop"><source src="//sedaulgen.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/Yasam-Enerjisi-1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

Another example of code:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('video.n2-ss-slide-background-video').forEach(video => {
        // Videoyu yüklenir yüklenmez durdur
        video.pause();
        video.removeAttribute('autoplay');
        video.muted = true; // Sesi kapat

        // Videonun üzerine gelindiğinde başlat
        video.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            video.play();
        });

        // Videodan ayrıldığında durdur
        video.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            video.pause();
        });
    });
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        document.querySelectorAll('video.n2-ss-slide-background-video').forEach(video => {
            video.removeAttribute('autoplay');
        });
    }, 1000); // Her saniyede bir kontrol eder
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('video.n2-ss-slide-background-video').forEach(video => {
    
        video.pause();
        video.removeAttribute('autoplay');
        video.muted = true; // Sesi kapat

       
        video.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            video.play();
        });

       
        video.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            video.pause();
        });
    });
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        document.querySelectorAll('video.n2-ss-slide-background-video').forEach(video => {
            video.removeAttribute('autoplay');
        });
    }, 1000); 
});


Are you loading a video from Vimeo hosting?

For a faster Answer, try to create a simple test page. No multiple scripts. Just simple code for one slider background video that must play on mouse-enter. Share the link to that simple page and someone will advise you.

Try replacing your code:
<video class="n2-ss-slide-background-video intrinsic-ignore data-tf-not-load" style="opacity:1;" data-mode="fill" playsinline="playsinline" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" onloadstart="this.n2LoadStarted=1;" data-keepplaying="1" preload="none" muted="muted" loop="loop"><source src="//sedaulgen.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/Yasam-Enerjisi-1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

With this new code:
<video 
class="n2-ss-slide-background-video intrinsic-ignore data-tf-not-load" 
style="opacity:1;" data-mode="fill" playsinline muted loop
onloadstart="this.n2LoadStarted=1;" data-keepplaying="0" preload="none">

<source src="//sedaulgen.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/Yasam-Enerjisi-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>

Now does that <video> only play on roll-over (or Enter) of mouse?
Old Answer:
You need to add one extra parameter in your URL to disable autoplay:
&amp;autoplay=0

You have code for an iframe, something like this:
<iframe 
class="elementor-video-iframe" allowfullscreen allow="clipboard-write" 
title="vimeo Video Oynatıcı" 
src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/888309521?color&amp;autopause=0&amp;loop=0&amp;muted=0&amp;title=1&amp;portrait=1&amp;byline=1#t="
>
</iframe>

Try changing the src part to become like below in your embed:
(also fix #t= to become #t=0 to play video from a starting time of zero.)
https://player.vimeo.com/video/888309521?color&amp;autoplay=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;loop=0&amp;muted=0&amp;title=1&amp;portrait=1&amp;byline=1#t=0


See if the update is useful to you. Otherwise you need to make a simple page showing the problem in action, for better advice about fixing it.
